# How to make UL Tabs with only HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, tabs, html-lists

Trying to figure out how to do this. I have the style but I'd like something to happen after I click the tabs. I would like the div with the tab class names to show and hide when i click the tabs. I'm assuming how that would work. Right now when I click the tabs nothing happens.

Here's my HTML

```
    <style type="text/css">
      ul.tabs {
          display: table;
          list-style-type: none;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
      }

      ul.tabs>li {
          float: left;
          padding: 10px;
          background-color: lightgray;
      }

      ul.tabs>li:hover {
          background-color: lightgray;
      }

      ul.tabs>li.selected {
          background-color: lightgray;
      }

      div.content {
          border: 1px solid black;
      }

      ul { overflow: auto; }

      div.content { clear: both; }
    </style>
<body>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab1">Description</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Specs</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="pane">
        <div class="tab1">
            <div><h2>Hello</h2></div>
        <div />
        <div>Hello hello hello.</div>
        <div />
        <div>Goodbye goodbye, goodbye</div>
        <div />
        <div />

        </div>
        <div class="tab2" style="display:none;">
        <div><h2>Hello2</h2></div>
        <div />
        <div>Hello2 hello2 hello2.</div>
        <div />
        <div>Goodbye2 goodbye2, goodbye2</div>
        <div />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        This should really appear on a new line.
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Your <a>s don't go anywhere, is that by design? Or did you mean the tab1 and tab2 classes to be ids?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Standard answer:** you can't. There is no way to do this with purely HTML/CSS2, unfortunately. We can make drop-downs in CSS with the `:hover` psuedo-class, but there's no equivalent for clicks. Look into one of these [Javascript-based solutions](http://speckyboy.com/2010/09/08/30-css-and-javascript-tabs-solutions/).

**Secret answer:** CSS3 [kind of] supports this. But you have to create radio buttons [weird], and it's not supported in IE7/8. [If you dare...](http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/)

And if you don't mind using Javascript, here's a quick solution. Reformatted your HTML, first of all. No need to put `<h2>`s in `<div>`s, and use `<br />` for breaks—that's what it's there for. Also, I changed the tab `<div>`s to use id's instead of classes. If you have unique identifiers for an element, use `id`.

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Description</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Specs</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="pane">
    <div id="tab1">
        <h2>Hello</h2>
        <p>Hello hello hello.</p>
        <p>Goodbye goodbye, goodbye</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" style="display:none;">
        <h2>Hello2</h2>
        <p>Hello2 hello2 hello2.</p>
        <p>Goodbye2 goodbye2, goodbye2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">This should really appear on a new line.</div>
```

Didn't touch your CSS.

For Javascript, I recommend using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). It *really* simplifies things.
All you need are these lines of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.tabs a").click(function() {
        $(".pane div").hide();
        $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    });
})
```

Basically, once the page is ready [has loaded], look for every link that's a child of a tabs `ul`. Attach a function that runs each time this link is clicked. When said link is clicked, hide all the tabs in the `.pane` div. Then, use the link's `href` to find the proper tab div and show it.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uFALn/18/

Answer (score 0):

Because of the floated `<li>` elements your `<ul>` element is zero height.

Try adding `ul { overflow: auto; }` and `div.content { clear: both; }` to your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Thanks benesch. It helped me too.

One can also add `return false` to prevent that jerky jump to the anchor. For instance:

```
$("ul.tabs a").click(function() {
    $(".pane div").hide();
    $($(this).attr("href")).show();
    return false;
});
```