# How to put all <li> elements in one line above regardless of the content within each <li>?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is there a way to put all li elements in one top-line regardless of the content within each li?
Here is a screen of how it should look like:
https://prnt.sc/11960bl?

The major difficulty is that when I write the code, the content within li moves all others li like so:
https://prnt.sc/11961wb

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="section-how__steps">
  <li class="section-how__step">
    <h3 class="section-how__step_of">1 step</h3>
    <div class="section-how__step_details">
      <h4 class="section-how__step_heading">Lorem Ipsum</h4>
      <p class="section-how__step_info">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. A, vero, expedita voluptate perferendis repudiandae dolorum velit veritatis, blanditiis et consequatur quasi esse itaque impedit quo. Placeat obcaecati dolore nesciunt ducimus! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et ullam iusto magnam qui nihil doloremque sit ab labore repudiandae sint aperiam repellat, natus, veritatis tempora necessitatibus asperiores est perferendis expedita?
      </p>
    <a class="section-how__button" href="">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    <a class="section-how__button" href="">Lore Ipsum</a>
    </div>
    <div class="section-how__banner">
      <a href="" class="section-how__banner_info"></a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="section-how__step">
    <h3 class="section-how__step_of">2 step</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="section-how__step">
    <h3 class="section-how__step_of">3 step</h3>
  </li>
  <li class="section-how__step">
    <h3 class="section-how__step_of">4 шаг</h3>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make UL Tabs with only HTML CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8708347/how-to-make-ul-tabs-with-only-html-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have pure CSS and HTML tabs, then [you can see this great article](https://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/).

```css
.tabs {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px; /* This part sucks */
  height: 100%;
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}
.tab {
  float: left;
}
.tab label {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
}
.tab [type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.content > * {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
}
[type="radio"]:focus ~ label {
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}
[type="radio"]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}
[type="radio"]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
[type="radio"]:checked ~ label ~ .content > * {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
      <label for="tab-1">Tab One</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Stuff for Tab One</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor
          quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean
          ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris
          placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed,
          commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci,
          sagittis tempus lacus
          enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus,
          tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis,
          accumsan porttitor, facilisis
          luctus, metus</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" id="tab-2" name="tab-group-1">
      <label for="tab-2">Tab Two</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Stuff for Tab Two</p>
        <img src="//placekitten.com/200/100">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab">
      <input type="radio" id="tab-3" name="tab-group-1">
      <label for="tab-3">Tab Three</label>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Stuff for Tab Three</p>
        <img src="//placekitten.com/200/100">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the same result, but let the div remain within the li?

Comment: @PavelPrusakov please, see my updated answer

Comment: @PavelPrusakov I am glad that it helped to you. Feel free to upvote! :)